# Deleting rows from a Matlab cell matrix which match a given pattern

Tags: matlab

I have a cell matrix with two columns (no headers).  Column one contains ticker symbols, e.g AAPL, GS etc. Column two contains either 0 or 1.

How can I delete all rows that contain '1' in column 2?  Then how can I get an output of the remaining ticker symbols separately in a different m file?

Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
>> a = {'AAPL', 1; 'MSFT', 0; 'GOOG' 1; 'IBM', 0} % Make some data like the OP's
a = 
    'AAPL'    [1]
    'MSFT'    [0]
    'GOOG'    [1]
    'IBM'     [0]
>> toDelete = cell2mat(a(:,2)) == 1; % Extract which rows have a 1 in column 2
>> a(toDelete,:) = []; % Delete those rows
>> remainingTickers = a(:,1) % Extract column 1 from the remaining rows
remainingTickers = 
    'MSFT'
    'IBM'
```

Comment: Many thanks, I used something similar( [num2cell(sym2bin)];rows_to_remove = any(sym2bin==1, 2);)  Now i have a next problem i have a matrix with 0's and 1's (347*347 double) called GMAT. I also have the remainingTickers single column matrix with 347 rows. How do i extraxt which columns and which rows are the ones with 1's from GMAT??? PLease help!! Meaning which pairs of timckers have 1...into a seperate mfile?

Comment: Great - glad it helped. If you have another separate question, you should mark the answer to this question as accepted, and ask the other question separately. You'll have a bit more space than in a comment to explain the problem fully.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215545/how-do-i-extract-which-row-and-columns-have-1-from-a-matrix-in-matlab

Comment: Thanks for separating the other question out. If the answer to this question has helped, you should also mark it as accepted by clicking the tick mark underneath the vote numbers.