# Extracting row and column names for matrix elements with a particular value?

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices relating to a list of 347 stocks.  The `remainingTickers` matrix is 347*1 and contains stock symbol names.  The `GMAT` matrix is 347*347 and contains `0` or `1` entries that indicate whether a pair of stocks have a correlation greater than 0.5.

I want to create a new matrix with two columns that consist of the pair of stock symbol names corresponding to the row and column for each `1` value in `GMAT`.  How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide a simple example ; your question is very hard to understand.

Comment: Hi Jacob, apologies. Basically i have 2 matrixes: Matrix 1 is a 347*347 Logical with 0's or 1's. If stock pairs have correlation greater that 0.5 then 1 otherwise 0. Matrix 2 is 347*1 Cell that includes stock tickers for the correlation matrix. I want to now create a new mfile that will list in two columns the pairs tickers from matrix 2 that have in Matrix one been identified with binary 1.

Comment: Use "find" to figure out where the 1's are.

Comment: @Jacob: I've edited the question to clarify it (incorporating much of Noob_1's explanatory comment); see if it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need something like:

```
[i, j] = find(GMAT);
left   = [remainingTickers(i)];
right  = [remainingTickers(j)];
```

`left{k}` and `right{k}` will form a pair that is correlated for any value of `k`.

Comment: @Noob_1: If this answer is useful to you, please upvote/accept it. For more details on how to ask questions at StackOverflow, please check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 0):

```
[a b] = find(gmat==1);
```

and eight more characters